# Checkin & Checkout columns in SQL Server 2012 reporting incorrect dates

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a SQL db table running on an attendance software. The software itself has default tables in the server with the correct times in one column only and differentiated by the checktype column. I wrote a query to separate the checktime column into 2 'start time' and 'end time' columns but the problem is that the default software table reports the correct time but my query does not.

#Here is my query:#

```
SELECT        
    USER_ID, 
    MIN(CONVERT(datetime, CAST(Start_Time AS datetime), 105)) AS [START TIME] (((same for end time)))
FROM
    (SELECT        
         dbo.USERINFO.BADGENUMBER, 
         CONVERT(VARCHAR, dbo.CHECKINOUT.CHECKTIME, 105) AS Date, 
         dbo.CHECKINOUT.CHECKTIME AS Start_Time, NULL AS End_Time
     FROM            
         dbo.USERINFO 
     CROSS JOIN
         dbo.CHECKINOUT
     WHERE        
         (dbo.CHECKINOUT.CHECKTYPE = 'I')
     UNION ALL
     SELECT        
         USERINFO_1.BADGENUMBER, 
         CONVERT(VARCHAR, View_ChronoInOut_1.CHECKTIME, 105) AS Date, 
         NULL AS Start_Time, View_ChronoInOut_1.CHECKTIME AS End_Time
     FROM            
         dbo.USERINFO AS USERINFO_1 
     CROSS JOIN
         dbo.CHECKINOUT AS View_ChronoInOut_1 
     CROSS JOIN
         dbo.USERINFO AS USERINFO_2
     WHERE        
         (View_ChronoInOut_1.CHECKTYPE = 'O')) AS fixTable2
GROUP BY 
    BADGENUMBER, Date
```

The output shows different times as follows:

Sample data from the software: [FOR ONE EMPLOYEE ONLY, OTHERS ARE SAME TOO]

| USERID | CHECKTIME | CHECKTYPE [I=CHECKIN, O=CHECKOUT] | DATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 22080 | 07:52:32 | I | 2020-12-10 |
| 22080 | 14:09:28 | O | 2020-12-10 |

Sample data from the table I created:

| USERID | START TIME | END TIME | WORK DATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 22080 | 06:32:32 | 18:12:08 | 2020-12-10 |

***UPDATE: I HAVE FOUND OUT THE PROBLEM. FOR SOME REASON THE USERIDS CHANGED IN THE DEVICE TO SINGLE NUMBERS (E.G 22080 BECAME 1). THEREFORE, THE TIMES GOT MESSED UP. I NEED TO KNOW IF THERE IS ANY WAY TO CHANGE THE USERIDS BACK TO WHAT THEY WERE.....***

Comment: Query's first line missing: ```SELECT USER_ID, MIN(CONVERT(datetime, CAST(Start_Time AS datetime), 105)) AS [START TIME] (((same for end time)))```

Comment: please edit your question and update with that

Comment: alright.. I didn't know you could create a table here... newbie here so very sorry for any inconvenience....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the data is always in I and O without any missing data, you can use `row_number()` to generate a sequential number and then `GROUP BY` `(RN - 1) / 2`, it will group 2 rows together

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT *, 
           RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY BADGENUMBER, CONVERT(DATE, CHECKTIME)
                                       ORDER BY CHECKTIME),
           CONVERT(TIME(0), CHECKTIME) AS WORK_TIME,
           CONVERT(DATE, CHECKTIME) AS WORK_DATE
    FROM   DBO.CHECKINOUT
)
SELECT BADGENUMBER AS USER_ID,
       MIN (WORK_TIME) AS START_TIME,
       MAX (WORK_TIME) AS END_TIME,
       WORK_DATE
FROM   CTE
GROUP BY BADGENUMBER, WORK_DATE, (RN - 1) / 2
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=826792e338a73d2dfd98ae0af9898a22)